# How to disable app background data usage via adb without root

Tags: adb, mobile-data, data-monitoring, bloatware, debloat

I'm trying to disable unnecessary apps and their background data usage on an Android 10 device, using the following commands:

```
 adb shell appops set package_name RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
 adb shell appops set package_name RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
 adb shell appops write-settings
 adb shell pm disable-user package_name
```

**Question:** How to disable background data usage for the package with ADB without root access?

Comment: There's no straightforward way. You can use `cmd netpolicy add restrict-background-blacklist <UID>` but it only restricts background data for the app if the network is metered (sets `REJECT_METERED_BACKGROUND` policy). You can achieve the same by disabling "Background network access" in the app's setting. A related answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214879/218526).

Comment: Thanks, so by adding "adb shell cmd netpolicy set restrict-background 1" it will restrict data usage system wide for all metered network? right?

Comment: Not system-wide. But for the given UID only. Every app has a UID.